# resaltar opcion de lista html al dar clic

Tags: html, css

como puedo hacer para que cuando se de clic en una opcion de una lista html se quede el backgroud de un color que resalte sobre las demas opciones, lo he realizado con la propiedad active pero no hace lo que requiero y con la propiedad hover pues si funciona pero solo pasando el mouse por encima pero cuando le doy clic desaparece el backgroud

```css
.enlace > a:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#">Liga 1</a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#">Liga 2</a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#">Liga 3</a></li>
  <li class="enlace"><a href="#">Liga 4</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres hacer es sólo resaltar el elemento o seleccionar varios a la vez?

Comment: @alexchvrches solo quiero resaltar el elemento

Comment: Si estás trabajando con **anchors** `<a>` al momento clic, y si la propiedad `href` está configurada, este te direccionará a otra página, no? Ahora bien, si quieres utilizar de todas formas la lista de **anchors** con un enlace muerto `#`, lo adecuado si es utilizar el cambio que te comenta @Andres Alvarez en la respuesta de abajo.

Comment: ¿Que es lo que buscas exactamente? ¿Que se mantenga pulsado hasta que vuelvas a hacer clic sobre otro elemento del menú o, que por el contrario, al hacer clic se pinte y que cuando pulses otro elemento este efecto desaparezca? Si es este último, la solución de @AndrésAlvarez sería lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de usar `a:hover` usa `a:focus` porque hover actúa al pasar el puntero del ratón encima de él.

En cambio focus actúa al seleccionar el elemento con el puntero del ratón o por uso del tabulador, pero a su vez pierde la permanencia con sólo pinchar en cualquier parte de la página. Saludos

Comment: Deberías explicar por qué lo que propones soluciona el problema.

Comment: Deberías explicar **en la respuesta** (*no en los comentarios*) por qué lo que propones soluciona el problema.

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta PaperBirdMaster. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres usar Jquery, podrias hacer lo siguiente,

```
$("#lista").click(function()
            {
                $("selected#lista").addClass("background:orange");
            })
```